# How can I fix this Webpack error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Yesterday I was running Webpack just fine with my current setup but when I got back to work on my project today I get this error:

```
/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/webpack.config.js:13
    output.path: "[name].js",
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:96:18)
```

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",

  entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js",
    javascript: "./js/app.js",
    html: "./index.html",
  },

  output: {
    output.path: "[name].js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    //chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' },
    extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules:[__dirname, './app/js', 'node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
        ],
        loaders: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: ["file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"],
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

I only added `app: "./src/app.js",` because I was having problems with webpack dev server. When I restarted webpack --watch I started getting this error. How can I fix this?

Comment: `output.path` isn’t a valid object property. If you really need a dot in there, use `"output.path"`.

Comment: Yeah, well, `output.path` *is* invalid syntax, *and* it's redundant with the next line too. **I guarantee that has _never_ worked as is.**

Comment: It's a JavaScript file, and as such, must be legal JS, which this isn't. Might want to take a small step back and make sure you understand the basics-there's no way, without pre-processing, that this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `output` is not [valid](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#configuration-object-content).

this

```
output: {
    output.path: "[name].js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    //chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
},
```

should be

```
output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
}
```

Comment: That cleared up the error, but now I get this https://pastebin.com/NP2u89Sp..any idea?